# Как сделать чтобы имя в диалоге сохранения по умолчанию подставлялось имя файла из диалога открытия

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать чтобы имя открываемого файла сохраняла данный файл с таким же именем. Используя данные функции tkinter

```
filedialog.askopenfilename()

filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

Окно открытия файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Окно сохранения файла - что бы в графе ввода отображалось название открытого файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Что такое `fitz`? Откуда он берется? Какое отношение это все имеет к tkinter, кроме диалога открытия файлов? Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начальная директория и имя файла в диалогах из модуля `filedialog` задаются через параметры `initialdir` и `initialfile` ([документация](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#native-load-save-dialogs)). Нужно получить полный путь из первого диалога, разбить на директорию и имя файла, и передать их во второй диалог:

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

full_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
directory, file_name = os.path.split(full_path)
filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=directory, initialfile=file_name)
```

То же самое через `pathlib` вместо `os.path` (["Почему вам следует использовать pathlib"](https://habr.com/ru/post/453862/)):

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import filedialog

full_path = Path(filedialog.askopenfilename())
filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=full_path.parent,
                             initialfile=full_path.name)
```